# Unable to Connect to BLE Device using Custom App without Workaround using nRF Connect

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

**Summary and Background of Problem**

As part of a college project, we are needing to connect to a Bluetooth LE module (BL654) with a custom app to update characteristics.

The issue is that I am unable to connect to our module without first doing a workaround. I am able to search for devices without issue and our module shows in the search. I would like the app to not have to rely on another app to work properly.

On a clean boot and clean OS install of the phone (Pixel 3XL / Pixel 3 / LG G5), I am unable to connect to our module. I am however able to connect to other BLE devices such as a Raspberry Pi and HTV Vive Base Stations.

The error I receive in the Android Studio Logcat is:

```
D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=133 clientIf=7 device=C2:A1:E0:B3:69:54
```

After then connecting to a **different** device using nRF Connect I am then able to connect to our module in nRF Connect, and subsequently our module within my app. Nordic makes both the firmware running on the board and nRF Connect. This leads me to believe something special is happening between the two?

I am using the standard Android libraries to make the connection and have also tried using RxAndroidBle.

I have researched for close to a month about this error and possible solutions and was unable to resolve it. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Here is a [Logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zGIgnC592OXOGj8_nVTP4N5AAijkEP-r/view?usp=sharing) of a failed connection attempt. Here is a [Logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mpb_x4BcSTQ8TFPvUKaPG4-ONc1qhrB8/view?usp=sharing) of a successful connection attempt after using the workaround.

Below I will show snippets of the relevant code. If more code is required I am happy to share.

**Code Snippets**

I have code split between a Kotlin Class file and MainActivity.kt, to my knowledge I am passing all the correct parameters between the two files. I am a beginner to Kotlin, so try to take it easy on me ;)

Finding Bluetooth Devices (Inside mBluetoothLEAdapter.kt):

```
fun findBluetoothDevices(mBluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter?){
        // Get and instance of the Bluetooth Low Energy Scanner
        scanner = mBluetoothAdapter?.bluetoothLeScanner

        // Create search settings object
        val mSettings = ScanSettings.Builder().
            setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).
            setReportDelay(reportDelay).
            build()

        // Create a scanning filter
        val mFilter = ScanFilter.Builder().setDeviceName("AEsir ADC Test").build()
        val scannerFilter = arrayListOf<ScanFilter>()
        scannerFilter.add(mFilter)

        // Stop previous scan if there was one
        stopScanningBluetoothDevices()

        //Start new scanner
        tools.showToast("Scanning...")
        scanner?.startScan(null, mSettings, mCallback)
    }
```

Scan Callback (Inside mBluetoothLEAdapter.kt):

```
inner class MCallBack: ScanCallback() {
        override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result)
            stopScanningBluetoothDevices()
            tools.showToast("Single Result Found!")
        }

        override fun onScanFailed(errorCode: Int) {
            super.onScanFailed(errorCode)
            stopScanningBluetoothDevices()
            tools.showToast("Error on Scan!")
            tools.showToast(errorCode.toString())
        }

        override fun onBatchScanResults(results: MutableList<ScanResult>?) {
            super.onBatchScanResults(results)
            stopScanningBluetoothDevices()
            tools.showToast("Batch Results Found!")
            scanResults = results
            val mAdapter = DeviceListAdapter(activity, scanResults)
            val deviceList = activity.findViewById<ListView>(R.id.device_list)
            deviceList.adapter = mAdapter
        }
    }
```

Connecting to a Device (Inside MainActivity.kt):

```
// Runs when an item in the Device List is pressed.
    // This initiates a GATT connection to the selected device.
    override fun onListPressed(): AdapterView.OnItemClickListener? {
        return AdapterView.OnItemClickListener { parent, _, position, _ ->

            if (bluetoothGatt != null) {
                bluetoothGatt?.disconnect()
                bluetoothGatt?.close()
            }

            val clickedItem = parent.getItemAtPosition(position) as ScanResult
            //val device = clickedItem.device
            val address = clickedItem.device.address
            tools.showToast("Connecting to: $address")

            // CONNECTION NOT WORKING. HAVE TO USE nRF Connect to make it work
            bluetoothGatt = clickedItem.device.connectGatt(applicationContext, false, mGattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)
        }
    }
```

GattCallback (Inside MainActivity.kt):

```
inner class GattCallback : BluetoothGattCallback() {
        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)
            //If we connected to the GATT server find services on device
            if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
                gatt.discoverServices()
            }
            else if (status == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTING) {
                tools.showToast("Connecting I am")
            }
            else if (status == BluetoothGatt.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
                bluetoothGatt?.close()
                bluetoothGatt = null
                tools.showToast("I got here and closed the connection")
            }
        }

        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, status: Int) {
            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)
            bluetoothServices = gatt?.services
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(gatt: BluetoothGatt, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic) {
            //"Notification"
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicWrite(gatt: BluetoothGatt?, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic?, status: Int) {
            super.onCharacteristicWrite(gatt, characteristic, status)

            //Confirm that the characteristic was actually changed
            tools.showToast("Characteristic was written!")
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicRead(gatt: BluetoothGatt, characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic, status: Int) {

        }

        override fun onDescriptorRead(gatt: BluetoothGatt, descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor, status: Int) {

        }
    }
```

> Thank you for any help you can offer :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the report delay to 0.

Your setup should now look like this

```
val mSettings = ScanSettings.Builder().
            setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY).
            setReportDelay(0).
            build()
```

You will also need to start using the single results callback instead of `onBatchScanResults`, which will require the list of results to be stored elsewhere.

```
override fun onScanResult(callbackType: Int, result: ScanResult?) {
//add to the list
//adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() if needed
}
```

I was having this issue in one of my apps and it seemed to be the fix.

If presenting a list to the user, it does seem like this makes the list update too quickly for a click to go through, so you may want to add your own delayed update without using `setReportDelay` if it becomes an issue

Comment: 133 error is a connection error, not related to scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the dreaded GATT 133 error.  This typically indicates that there is something wrong in Android's BLE stack, and resetting Bluetooth - and WiFi on older devices - will often resolve.

Your workaround works because Android allows a Bluetooth device, connected in one app, to be shared across other apps.  Seems like an awful security vulnerability, but is expected behavior.

Judging from your experience, however, it's entirely possible the peripheral has an unexpected configuration.  Perhaps try out [RxCentralBle](https://github.com/uber/RxCentralBle) - Uber's library for Bluetooth LE integrations - sample app and see if that works for connecting to your device.  The sample app and library are open source, so you can adapt however you see fit.

Full disclosure - I am the author and maintainer of RxCentralBle.